# JOIN Two table in DJANGO with aggregate

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate

I've been playing around with django for a month now and i'm stuck with JOINING Two tables with Aggregate with it. Here's my models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_number_format = RegexValidator(regex=r"^20{1,2}[1-2][0-9]-[0-9]{6}", message="Please enter a valid student number (example:2019-123456)")
    student_number  = models.CharField(validators=[student_number_format], max_length=11, blank=True, unique=True, help_text="Student number must be this format 20YY-99999")
    student_course  = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    middle_initial  = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    date_registered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class DataSets(models.Model):
    student_info  = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataset_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=dataset_directory_path)
    date_upload   = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

In here i have two models the DataSets class have a Foreign Key to Student. And i want to show only is Students that have 5 or more data inside DataSets. Here's the SQL representation:

```
SELECT Count(student_info) as Count, A.first_name as Name 
FROM Student A
JOIN DataSets B ON A.id = B.student_info_id
WHERE Count >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `select_related`[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) . I hope following query will work.

```
DataSets.objects.select_related('student_info').annotate(
     entries=models.count()).filter(entries__gte=5)
```

Comment: Well i tried your code but i just return an empty  QuerySet. Thanks thou

Comment: @CarlDennisAlingalan instead of `student_info_id` can you please try with just `student_info`.

Comment: Yeah i create a function inside the models.py then my next problem is that when i use the 'self' argument in my function it actually ask me to give it a parameters. Here's my code

Comment: ` def valid_student(self):valid = self.values('student_info').annotate(entries=models.Count('student_info')).filter(entries__gte=5)
  student = [Student.objects.get(id=stud_num['student_info']) for stud_num in valid]  
  return student`

Comment: Here's how i use it 

liststud = DataSets.valid_student(DataSets.objects)

Comment: Great. I have a request, if you think this answer is good enough to be accepted, kindly please accept this as answer of this. So that other people may know about that current situation of the question.

Comment: btw if you think this isn't the solution you are looking for. Then you can post your own answer in two days and can accept that. This will let other people know about it, who will face similar kind of problem.

Comment: @CarlDennisAlingalan i have a concern about your solution and telling your freely. Your for loop query will be costly as this is hitting `db` every time. If possible we should always avoid these type of case. `select_related` actually look_up foreignkey relation and should perform this in `db` level with one query. I am not sure about your  case why my proposed solution didn't work but you can add `select_related` relation end of query. As Django perform lazy query all thing will happen sequentially in a single `db` hit.